# GitLab Pages, docs generated with sphinx

Tags: gitlab, python-sphinx, gitlab-ci

I want to host static page generated with Sphinx on GitLab Pages. Built `index.html` file is in:

```
project/docs/build/html
```

How  `.gitlab-ci.yml` should look like to deploy the page? I have something like that and it isn't working:

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - echo 'Nothing to do...'
 artifacts:
 paths:
 - docs/build/html
 only:
 - master
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the [documentation for .gitlab-ci.yml](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#pages), the `pages` job has special rules it *must* follow:

> 1. Any static content must be placed under a `public/` directory
> 2. `artifacts` with a path to the `public/` directory must be defined

So the example `.gitlab-ci.yml` you gave would look something like this:

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mv docs/build/html/ public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

And of course, if you don't want to move the `html` folder for whatever reason, you can copy it instead.

For further reference, [an example `sphinx` project for GitLab Pages](https://gitlab.com/pages/sphinx) was pushed around the time you originally posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
image: python:3.10-alpine

stages:
  - deploy

pages:
  tags:
    - sphinx
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - python3 -m pip install sphinx furo
    - sphinx-build -b html docs/source/ public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - main # 'master' was renamed to 'main'
```

This is what my `GitLab-ci.yml` looks like.
On a side note: You don't need a `public`-folder in your repository. GitLab itself will handle it. I installed `furo` as theme (make sure to change the `conf.py` accordingly) to make it look nicer.